# No NullPointerException in JSTL when calling methods on null object associated with request object.why?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception, dispatcher

Yesterday I appeared in an interview. The interviewer shows me this code and asked-

```
<c:when test='${hobby.equals("hobby1")}'>
```

Why there is no null pointer, while the value of `hobby` is  `null`

Code is as-

> In `Sevlet class`-

```
request.setAttribute("hobby", null);
request.getRequestDispatcher("display.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

> In `display.jsp`-

```
<c:when test='${hobby.equals("hobby1")}'>
```

Comment: JSTL and EL are used to render view hence exception and null variable are treated with blank white space.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JSTL nearly always suppresses NullPointerExceptions.  There is a brief discussion [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/289665/JSP/java/null-JSTL) and more detail can be found in section [3.6 of the JSTL spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jstl-1.1-mr2-spec-oth-JSpec/jstl-1_1-mr2-spec.pdf).